# How to create a single data frame with multiple vectors result of a loop operation?

Tags: r, audio, wav

I have a .wav file and want to get power spectrums for successive no overlapping time windows.
The data of the power spectrum is obtained with the next function, once `seewave` and `tuneR` libraries are loaded:

```
 n <- 0:1 
 sound1 <- readWave("D:\\sound.wav")
 result <- do.call(cbind, lapply(n, function(x) 
 meanspec(sound1,from=x,to=x+1,wl=16,plot=FALSE)))
 result1 <- data.frame(result)
```

The ouput will be

```
 structure(list(x = c(0, 2.75625, 5.5125, 8.26875, 11.025, 13.78125, 
 16.5375, 19.29375), y = c(1, 0.551383594277632, 0.0742584974502194, 
 0.0399059818168578, 0.0218500553648978, 0.0176655910374274, 
 0.00904887363707214, 
 0.00333698474894753), x.1 = c(0, 2.75625, 5.5125, 8.26875, 11.025, 
 13.78125, 16.5375, 19.29375), y.1 = c(1, 0.558106398109396, 
 0.145460335046358, 
 0.0804097312947365, 0.0476025570412434, 0.0393549921764155, 
 0.0203584314573552, 
 0.00737927765210362)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
```

But in the resultant df I only need **y** and **y.1** but no **x** and **x.1**. As you may notice **x** and **1.x** have the same data and such iformation is redundant. In short: I only need **y** data.

Thankyou for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

There are more than a few ways to do what you are talking about. I don't know the length of the vector you are talking about though or the way meanspec returns its data, so you will have to fill that in yourself

```
vec_length <- length(amplitude_vector)
wav_df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = vec_length + 1))

for(i in 0:(end-1)){
    #Add relevant code to get the amplitude vector from the function below
    amp_vec <- meanspec(sound1, from = i, to = i+1, plot = FALSE)... 
    wav_df <- rbind(wav_df,c(i,amp_vec))
}

colnames(wav_df) <- c("start-time",...)#Add in the other column names that you want
```

`wav_df` should then have the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `lapply` -

```
n <- 0:9 #to end at 9-10;change as per your preference
Sound1 <- readWave("D:\\Sound.wav")
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(n, function(x) 
                  meanspec(sound1,from=x,to=x+1,plot=FALSE)))
result
#to get dataframe as output
#result <- data.frame(result)
```

Comment: Changing ``cbind`` for ``rbind`` I am able to get the df I need. But actually I need the df without the frequency reduntant values. That is: only the **y** values, but no the **x** values. @ronakshah